# Prioritizing * and / in binary expression

Tags: javascript

If i have these tokens :

```
[
 { type: "Literal", value: 1 },
 { type: "Operator", value: "+" },
 { type: "Literal", value: 2 },
 { type: "Operator", value: "*" },
 { type: "Literal", value: 3 },
 { type: "Operator", value: "+" },
 { type: "Literal", value: 4 }
]
```

How can i turn those tokens into a tree like this :

```
{
 type: "BinaryExpression",
 left: {
  type: "BinaryExpression",
  left: { type: "Literal", value: 1 },
  operator: { type: "Operator", value: "+" },
  right: {
   type: "BinaryExpression",
   left: { type: "Literal", value: 2 },
   operator: { type: "Operator", value: "*" },
   right: { type: "Literal", value: 3 }
  }
 },
 operator: { type: "Operator", value: "+" },
 right: { type: "Literal", value: 4 }
}
```

I have read about *recursive descent parsing* but i can't really understand it

Comment: Read about operator precedence when parsing.

Answer (score 1):

you can check for `*` or `/` operators before any other operator. Here is the code:

```
var parsed = [
    { type: "Literal", value: 1 },
    { type: "Operator", value: "+" },
    { type: "Literal", value: 2 },
    { type: "Operator", value: "*" },
    { type: "Literal", value: 3 },
    { type: "Operator", value: "+" },
    { type: "Literal", value: 4 },
];

function makeTree(parsed) {
    console.log("dbg1", parsed);
    while (parsed.length > 1) {
        // check for * operator
        var foundmul = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < parsed.length; i++) {
            if (parsed[i].type === "Operator" && parsed[i].value === "*") {
                if (
                    i < 1 ||
                    i > parsed.length - 2 ||
                    parsed[i + 1].type === "Operator" ||
                    parsed[i - 1].type === "Operator"
                ) {
                    throw new Error("Invalid expression");
                } else {
                    var subtree = {
                        type: "BinaryExpression",
                        operator: parsed[i],
                        left: parsed[i - 1],
                        right: parsed[i + 1],
                    };
                    parsed.splice(i - 1, 3, subtree);
                    foundmul = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (foundmul) {
            continue;
        }

        // check for + operator
        for (var i = 0; i < parsed.length; i++) {
            if (parsed[i].type === "Operator" && parsed[i].value === "+") {
                if (
                    i < 1 ||
                    i > parsed.length - 2 ||
                    parsed[i + 1].type === "Operator" ||
                    parsed[i - 1].type === "Operator"
                ) {
                    throw new Error("Invalid expression");
                } else {
                    console.log("dbg2", parsed.slice(0, i));
                    console.log("dbg2.1", parsed.slice(i + 1, parsed.length));
                    console.log("dbg2.2", i);
                    var subtree = {
                        type: "BinaryExpression",
                        operator: parsed[i],
                        left: makeTree(parsed.slice(0, i)),
                        right: makeTree(parsed.slice(i + 1, parsed.length)),
                    };
                    parsed = [subtree];
                    // parsed = [ { type: "Literal", value: 4 } ];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return parsed[0];
}

var tree = makeTree(parsed);
console.log("dbg3", tree, tree.right.left);
```